# RAW SQL Query with Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

Is there a way to execute a SQL String as a query in Zend Framework?

I have a string like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE myColumn = 5"
```

now I want to execute this string directly withput parsing it and creating a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object from it "by hand". Or if thats possible create a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object from this string, to execute that object.

How can I do that? I didn't find a solution for this in the Zend doc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're creating a Zend_DB object at the start you can create a query using that. Have a look at this entry in the manual : https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html

```
$stmt = $db->query(
            'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?',
            array('goofy', 'FIXED')
        );
```

Or

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?';
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($db, $sql);
$stmt->execute(array('goofy', 'FIXED'));
```

Comment: does `$db->query($sql, array())` work also? because I do have the parameters already qouted into the string!? And do I have to fetch the resultSet with `$stmt->fetchAll()` ?

Comment: For the sake of completeness: yes, $stmt->fetchAll() will get the results.

Comment: Most of the times, it's better to use the framework since there a lot of automatic protections. But sometimes you want to optimize a query or get some very specific data. Those times there are no ways around writing custom queries. Just make sure to sanitize your query properly.

Comment: I declare $db =Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter(); inside my model's function

Answer (score 5):

If you are using tableGateway, you can run your raw SQL query using this statement,

```
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);
```

where $sql pertains to your raw query. This can be useful for queries that do not have native ZF2 counterpart like TRUNCATE / INSERT SELECT statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same query in Zend format as

```
$select = db->select()->from(array('t' => 'testTable'))
                     ->$where= $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('myColumn = ?', $s);
$stmt = $select->query();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: You don't need to use quoteInto() here. where() will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for ZF1:

```
$db =Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$sql =    "select * from user"
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$users =  $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: for me it doesn't work, btw where I have to define $db variable mention above, in my class that extends from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract or in my controller?

Comment: @adm you can use **$db =Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();** anywhrere. The above code is from my controller.

Comment: It gives me an error like this : 
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/tmtmedia/public_html/trakmysafari/application/models/trip.php on line 199

Comment: you can use the above code in controller. 

If you have a class (e.g. MyModel) that extends with **Zend_Db_Table_Abstract** then try to check all the public functions using "get_class_methods" and if you find getDefaultAdapter() then you can use this code in the class (MyModel): **$rows = $this->getDefaultAdapter()->query("select * from mytable")->fetchAll();**