# add multi tables in from() zend_db_select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

i have to do a select from multi tables using zend_db_select for this sql :

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.ids, t3.uid 
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2, table3 t3
```

this is the code used :

```
$subQuery = $this->getDbTable ()->select ()->setIntegrityCheck ( false )
->from(array('t1'=>'table1','t2'=>'table2','t3'=>'table3'),array('t1.id','t2.ids','t3.uid'))
->query()
->fetchAll();
```

so i have message error say that t2.ids is not in the column list
because zend_db_select take just the first table

any solution to resolve this problème ?
thaks

Comment: Is there any relation between `t1.id`, `t2.ids` and `t3.uid`? Maybe you could re-write your SQL query based on JOINs.

Comment: there is no relations between tables

Comment: Well, in that case you can always execute your [raw MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161370/raw-sql-query-with-zend-framework).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross join with:

```
$subQuery = $this->getDbTable ()->select ()->setIntegrityCheck ( false )
->from(array('t1'=>'table1'),array('t1.id'))
->joinCross(array('t2'=>'table2'),array('t2.ids'))
->joinCross(array('t3'=>'table3'),array('t3.uid'))
->query()
->fetchAll();
```